# Linux Cumulative User, System CPU Usage of Running Process?

Tags: linux, time, cpu-usage, monitoring

On Linux (and other Unix-like OS's if there's a general answer), is there an easy way to get an output similar to the `time` command (current real time, user, and system CPU usage totals) for a process that is still running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, check out `/proc/$PID/stat`, that should have what you need. The fields are defined in `man proc`. Can also pull memory usage and fault information, if you care about taht.